# Use Functions from one Google Script in many different tables (google-sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I wrote the google-script. In that script I have a function that I need to use in 250+ different tables (google-sheets). Question is - How can I make it function accessible in each table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fond the solution. In my case files that I need to change is placed in deferent folders and have similar name

```
// function that i need to execute
function updatePrices(sheetId){    
  // do some staff
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var histPricesSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(someSheetName);
  ....
  var cell = histPricesSheet.getRange(range);
  cell.setValues(someData);
}


function walkFolders(folderId){    
  // function that walk by folders and get ids of spradsheeds 
  and call func that I need in each spradsheed that I need

  var fin_fold = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); 
  var folders = fin_fold.getFolders();

  while (folders.hasNext()) {

    var folder = folders.next();
    var files = folder.searchFiles('title contains "карточка"');

    while (files.hasNext()){

      var file = files.next();

      updatePrices(file.getId());    // call my function to every spreadsheet
      Logger.log("обновлено");
    }
  }
}

walkFolders("folder ID wich contain folders with files to change");
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a script or custom function available across other Google Sheets, publish it as a library.

Bruce Mcpherson has a nice post on how to do this: http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gooscript/lib

Comment: by that way I can use my func in sheet only after creation new project in each table and import that library with my func and call in new func in new project from imported project? May be is there a solution to just write `=myLib.myFunc()` in cell?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Two options:

- Create a Apps Script project that calls the 250+ spreadsheet, makes the operations and  updates each spreadsheet which the results.

On this you'll find a collection of tutorials to start with apps script.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials

- Create a function that you can call from any cell of your spreadsheet just as you call any other default function like SUM()

On this documentation you'll find explained how to do this second option.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments